# What is the output of parenthesis in php?

Tags: php, parentheses

```
$number = 1;
```

This is valid:

```
$number = ($number) + 1;
```

But this is invalid:

```
$number = ($number) ++;
```

So why I can use `+ 1` and increase it but I cannot use `++` to increase it?

Comment: Parentheses effective group code statements into blocks and provide a result..... so doing $number = ($number) ++; is trying to increment a an unassigned result, not a variable, which you can't do; `$number = ($number) + 1;` simply gets the "result" of number and you can add 1 to that, so it's valid

Comment: `()` doesn't have [l-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29#lrvalue).

Comment: @MarkBaker Can I say the priority of executing `++` is more than `()` ?

Comment: @Alex - don't understand what you're saying there.... no, parentheses have priority over all operators, else BODMAS would be meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$number = ($number) + 1;
```

This is valid because you add 1 to an expression.

`++` as increment operator cannot be used for expressions it can be used only for variables.

From manual:

> The increment/decrement operators only affect numbers and strings.

Answer (score 0):

Increment operator `++` increments numbers or string variables. `($number)` is not a variable but an expression.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason that these are valid:

```
isset($_GET['foo'])
$bar++;
$data = array(1, 5, 6);
sort($data);
```

... and these are not:

```
isset('hi');
'hi'++;
33++;
sort(array(1, 5, 6));
```

Some functions, operators and constructs operate on **variables** and don't make sense elsewhere. Parenthesis here are basically a red herring.